# Java hierarchy and object array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, hierarchy

I have a lot of questions about this piece of code that I am writing for a school project. I am trying to do this:

Create and implement a class hierarchy where Vehicle superclass and 'Motorcycle' and 'Truck' are the subclasses.

- Common to both Motorcycle and Truck are the variables wheels and weight and the method display( ). The attributes should not be accessible outside the class. display( ) will printout the wheels and weight and should only be accessible to the common class and all subclasses.
- Data unique to the Motorcycle class should be passengers. Data unique to the Truck class should be payload. Include methods to display this information.
- Draw the class hierarchy.
- Create a 'driver' class to test your hierarchy. Allow for the creation of multiple objects by the user by storing the references in an array of Vehicle. You should allow the user to create a motorcycle object by entering 'm', and then ask for relevant attributes. Along the same lines, use 't' to create the truck object.
- After inputting all data, print out the contents of each object by calling the display( ) method. Print the number of passengers in case of a motorcycle or the payload in case of a truck. Note that the display( ) method will have to be overridden for the different subclasses

Here is my crude code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Hierarchy{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Vehicle [] garage = new Vehicle [3];
        for(int i = 0; i< garage.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter 't' to create a truck, and 'm' for a motorcycle");
            String charIn = in.nextLine();
            if(charIn == "m"){
                System.out.println("What is the payload of the Truck");
                int payload = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the weight of the Truck");
                int weight = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many wheels does the Truck have");
                int wheels = in.nextInt();
                garage[i] = new Truck(payload, wheels, weight);
            }else{
                System.out.println("How many passengers can the Motorcycle seat");
                int passengers = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the weight of the Motorcycle");
                int weight = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many wheels does the Motorcycle have");
                int wheels = in.nextInt();
                garage[i] = new Motorcycle(passengers, weight, wheels);
            }
        }
        //display();
    }
}


class Vehicle{
    int wheels;
    int weight;
    public Vehicle(int wheels, int weight){
        weight = this.weight;
        wheels = this.wheels;
    }
    //private void display(int weight, int passengers, int wheels){
    //}
    //private void display(int weight, int payload, int wheels){
    //}

}

class Truck extends Vehicle{
    int payload;
    public int getWheels(){
        return wheels;
    }
    public int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public Truck(int wheels, int payload, int weight){
        super(wheels, weight);
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle{
    int passengers;
    public int getWheels(){
        return wheels;
    }
    public int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public Motorcycle(int wheels, int passengers, int weight){
        super(wheels, weight);
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }
}
```

I've tried looking around in as many resources as I can, but I can't see a way to input data into the superclass and subclass, and then put the information into one object (the garage array). Also, can anyone give me some methods for printing out the data in objects of the garage array? And of course, if you see any stupid mistakes, feel free to tell me.
Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: For printing arrays nicely, `Arrays.toString(someArray)` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the following:

```
class Vehicle {
    int wheels;
    int weight;
    public Vehicle(int wheels, int weight){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }

    public int getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {
    int payload;

    public Truck(int wheels, int payload, int weight){
        super(wheels, weight);
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // todo - write code to output the truck details as a string
        return "truck details here";
    }
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle{
    int passengers;

    public Motorcycle(int wheels, int passengers, int weight){
        super(wheels, weight);
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // todo - write code to output the motorcycle details as a string
        return "motorcycle details here";
    }
}
```

Your code to create the trucks and motorcycles and put them into the Vehicle array looks fine.

When you want to print them out, just loop throught the array calling toString on each object and printing it out:

```
for(Vehicle vehicle : garage) {
    System.out.println(vehicle.toString());
}
```

Additionally, you test if `charIn == 'm'` but you create a truck instead of a motorcycle. If the user enters anything other than `m` then you create a motorcycle.